# convert date in strtotime format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var time=d.toLocaleDateString();
    alert(time);
```

Now i want to convert the **date** in strtotime format in js.But can't!!!
i want to convert it.when i use **Date.parse()** it shows **Nan**.

i want to display date as "1401141600"
Guide me!!

Comment: why not simply use d.getTime() , it gives the same result.

Comment: i don't want the time ji...i'm using date...so need to convert the date alone.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to display the time only, use: `d.toLocaleTimeString();` it should output something like `"10:32:06 AM"`

Otherwise, if you need the date `Tue May 27 2014 00:00:00` in milliseconds.. go for `d.setHours(0,0,0)` to reset the hours, minutes and seconds. Then use `d.getTime()` to display `1401141600207`. If you want to ignore the last 3 digits, use `Math.floor(d.getTime()/1000)` to get `1401141600`.

Comment: No ya... when i'm using getDate() it literally displays "27", i don't want that format. i want to convert it.

Comment: i need date alone...When we use getTime() it shows somethin like "11899099".now i want to convert getDate() like that.

Comment: oh the date alone would be `d.toLocaleDateString()` then, does this work for you?

Comment: Please specify Which format you want the date should be.

Comment: i want to display date as "1401141600", actually the numbers for today's full date format(27-may-2014)...i want like this for 27 alone

Comment: In other words, you need the date `Tue May 27 2014 00:00:00` in milliseconds.. so go for `d.setHours(0,0,0)` to reset the hours, minutes and seconds. Then use `d.getTime()` to display `1401141600207` If you want to ignore the last 3 digits, use `Math.floor(d.getTime()/1000)` to get `1401141600`

Answer (score 0):

Try fill the parameters `Date.parse(time)` so it won't become `NaN`
and you get time like strtotime in php.

Comment: it is giving NaN, when i pass 9:00